# How to get the name and status of all IIS application pools in C#?

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, windows-services

I want to capture the all application pool name and its status in IIS.

Planning to develop a windows service for getting the IIS Application Pool Name and Its Status i.e. Running Or Stopped. How can I achieve this?

Please provide sample example if any.
Appreciate any Help.
Thanks..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Enumerating Application Pools in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400464/enumerating-application-pools-in-iis).

```
DirectoryEntries appPools = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools").Children;
```